# asp.net Identity authentication .net core 2.1

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm having an issue with a .net core 2.1 MVC application that is running on Linux boxes using kestrel behind an nginx web server. This environment has 2 web servers behind a load balancer.

The issue is the .AspNetCore.Identity.Application cookie used for authentication. I am able to authenticate and redirected to a controller decorated with the

> [Authorize]

attribute (sometimes). However, on the next request, the cookie's gone and I get a 401. When we take one server out of the mix and force all traffic to one server, everything works as expected.

With Forms auth, the same problem could be overcome with specifying the machine key. What's the equivalent for .net core using identity? I found some links that went over my head. They mention doing something like this:

```
 services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
 {
     options.ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
 });
```

I have no idea if this will fix the issue and I don't want to try things without knowing what they do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect what you experience has to do with data protection.

ASP.NET Core cookie authentication relies on the data protection layer to encrypt and decrypt data stored in the cookies. By default, a local key is created on each machine, meaning they can't decrypt cookies created by the other one, as [stated in the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/web-farm?view=aspnetcore-2.1#data-protection).

I suggest that you go through the [data protection configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x) documentation page and evaluate your options. One of them is to [store the keys on a UNC share](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x#persistkeystofilesystem) and [encrypt them with a certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x#protectkeyswith) (all the links in this paragraph link to different sections of the same page).

Comment: Thanks. I'll check it out.